# How to disable internet from enp2s0 adaptor

Tags: centos, networking, network-interface, networkmanager

I have tow network adaptor attached to centos 8 and both have internet i just want to disable internet one of the network adaptor and keep LAN access only whenever i reboot server the internet connection change randomly. i want to keep eno1 adaptor my default network.

USB network adaptor what to disable internet on it and keep LAN

```
enp2s0
```

Network Network card adaptor i want to enable internet default even after reboot server

```
eno1
```

Comment: what is preventing you from achieving that? ... what research have you done?

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Comment: no its not a school assignment. basically i have very complicated network environment. i have dedicated and shared data connections on the same server i have squid proxy server running and 300 windows clients getting internet for browsing through proxy server which is shared connection whenever server reboot connection shift to dedicated network  which we only use for remote branches VPN tunnel.